Small doubt regarding proof of Replacement under Von Neumann Universe
As title states, I have a small doubt concerning how exactly the Replacament axiom schema is proven to hold for the Von Neumann universe $V = \bigcup_{\alpha \in \mathrm{Ord}}V_\alpha$. As I understand it, the relative consistency proofs for these sort of class models are supposed to show that the (relativized) axioms do indeed hold in the class at hand. So, for example, it should be the case that $\mathsf{ZFC} \models \forall xy \in V \ \exists z \in V \ \forall w \in V \ (w \in z \leftrightarrow w = x \lor w = y)$ (Pairs), etc. My question is: how is Replacement proven to hold under $V$? The usual proof that I see being utilized basically shows that (together with Foundation), every set has a rank $\mathrm{rank}(x)$, so the axioms should be proven to hold for $V_0$ (all sets of rank $0$), and then via transfinite induction to hold for $V_{\beta+1}$ and $V_\lambda$ (and thus for all $V_\alpha$, i.e., for $V$ itself). My question is: how exactly does one prove that Replacement holds given that all axioms have held up till a stage $\alpha$? Is it because the resulting image-set should have a similar rank? I'm a tad confused as Replacement seems to be able to "get one far away" from the sets they may be working with at hand.
Thank you for any and all answers!

I'm confused. In ZFC, V is the whole universe, so all the axioms hold in V because they're axioms.

Maybe more precisely: Since $\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash \forall x(x\in V)$, for every sentence $\varphi$, $\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash \varphi\leftrightarrow \varphi^V$. In particular, every instance of replacement is equivalent to its relativization to $V$.

I’m guessing you aren’t assuming foundation in the background?

@AlexKruckman I mean $\mathsf{WF} = \bigcup_{\alpha \in \mathrm{Ord}}V_\alpha$ and how to prove that the relativized axioms hold for this class. I do not mean $V$ as in the class defined by $x = x$. I apologize for the poor choice of notation.

@spaceisdarkgreen I would be proving $\mathsf{ZFC} \vdash \mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) \rightarrow \mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC} + \mathrm{Reg})$ (as I understand it) by showing the relativized axioms to hold for $\mathsf{WF} = \bigcup_{\alpha \in \mathrm{Ord}}V_\alpha$. My question is how exactly one proves the relativized version of Replacement.

@Sho Reg is part of ZFC. You mean proving Con(ZFC-Reg) implies Con(ZFC)? As Alex mentions, ZFC proves $V=WF$ ($V=WF$ is equivalent to regularity over ZFC-regularity).

@Sho (or maybe Alex didn’t mention that, but the point is if you don’t drop regularity, you can just prove WF is the whole universe and his point stands)

@spaceisdarkgreen Yes. I mean to prove that Con(ZFC – Reg) implies Con(ZFC). How is the Replacement part of that justified?

@Sho By applying the axiom of replacement on the formula relativized to WF and observing that the set it says exists is necessarily in WF.

@spaceisdarkgreen Thank you. I think I sort of get it now. Is there a book you would recommend to get these matters sorted? (So that I can perhaps see how the justification of the image-set being in WF without assuming Regularity goes about.) Either way, thank you once again for the patience!

@Sho Kunen 1980 has a thorough treatment. (The newer Kunen probably does too but I don’t remember it as well.)

Ignoring parameters for convenience, if $A\in\bf WF$ and for all $x\in A,$ there is a unique $y\in \bf WF$ such that $\varphi^{\bf WF}(x,y),$ then by the replacement instance for $\varphi^{\bf WF},$ there is a set $B$ consisting exactly of all $y$ in the “range”. Since every such $y$ is well-founded, $B\in\bf WF$. Thus the replacement instance for $\varphi$ holds relative to $\bf WF$.
In general, for proving $\bf WF$ satisfies ZFC, the fact that $\bf WF$ is supertransitive (i.e. $ A\subseteq \mathbf {WF}\leftrightarrow A\in\bf WF$) is very useful.
